# Cartesian product of Power Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have to prove or disprove the following:

$$\mathcal{P}(A \times B)= \mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(B)$$

where $\mathcal{P}$ here is power set. I tried to do it using the definition, but I feel like there should be an easier way of proving or disproving it.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: Does X denote the cartesian product?

Comment: Does your "$=$" actually mean equality of sets? If so, why "cardinal" in the title?

Comment: Sorry yes, the X denotes the cartesian product.

Comment: The correct statement is that $\wp(A)\times\wp(B)$ is naturally in bijection with $\wp(A\amalg B)$ (where $\amalg$ is disjoint union), not $\wp(A\times B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to see that it cannot always be true is to examine the cardinalities of the two sets.

There are $2^{|A|}$ elements in the powerset of some set $A$. The cardinality of the cartesian product $A \times B$ of two sets is $|A||B|$.

Using the above information, we have $$|\mathcal{P}(A \times B)|=2^{|A \times B|}=2^{|A||B|}$$
and 
$$|\mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(B)|=|\mathcal{P}(A)||\mathcal{P}(B)|=2^{|A|}2^{|B|}=2^{|A|+|B|}.$$

So we have shown that
$$\mathcal{P}(A \times B)= \mathcal{P}(A) \times \mathcal{P}(B)$$

is not true when $|A||B|\neq|A|+|B|$.

Comment: Note: This shows that the statement is *not always* true for sets $A, B$. Riley's answer shows that it is *never* true.

Answer (score 3):

It is false for all sets $A,B$. We have $\emptyset \in \mathcal{P}(A\times B)$ but $\emptyset \notin (\mathcal{P}(A)\times \mathcal{P}(B))$.